# Sending request to GCM results in a JSON_PARSIN_ERROR

Tags: java, android, push-notification, push, google-cloud-messaging

I need to write a server which sends push notifications to iOS and Android devices.

I can successfully send notifications to iOS. Luckily it was painless to implement that part.

I'm facing a problem with the easiest part of the task: Android.

I configured GCM and the Android device successfully registers against the server.

When I try to send a push to the device, I get the following error:

```
STATUS: 400
JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected token END OF FILE at position 0.
```

Here the code that sends the request.

```
AndroidPush push = new AndroidPush();
push.getRegids().add(token);
push.getData().setMessage(message);
push.getData().setMsgcnt(String.format("%d", (badge + 1)));

URL u = new URL(androidEndpoint);
HttpsURLConnection conn = null;
OutputStream os = null;
OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
InputStream is = null;
InputStreamReader isr = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
try{

    conn = (HttpsURLConnection)u.openConnection();

    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", androidContentType);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", androidAuthorization);

    conn.connect();

    os = conn.getOutputStream();
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);   

    System.out.println(push.toJSON());
    osw.write(push.toJSON());

    int status = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.err.println("STATUS: "+status);
    if(status == 200){
        is = conn.getInputStream();
    } else {
        is = conn.getErrorStream();
    }
    isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    br = new BufferedReader(isr); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String read = null;
    do {
        read = br.readLine();
        if(read != null)
            sb.append(read);
    } while (read != null);

    if(status != 200){
        System.err.println(sb.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }

} catch(IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    throw ex;
} finally {
    if(isr != null)
        isr.close();
    if(is != null)
        is.close();
    if(osw != null)
        osw.close();
    if(os != null)
        os.close();
    if(conn != null)
        conn.disconnect();
}
```

Where:

```
androidEndpoint = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";
androidContentType = "application/json";
androidAuthorization = "key=<mykey>";
```

and the output of the push.toJSON() method is the following String:

```
{
    "registration_ids" : ["APA91bEmD8T9NxQj07uhbTAsD1GTWvT7L_no1SXP70YWaQGPX6VO73pdAOa53PN-hyAyy-3erItWxLDb8W1aQ2nh3np0NttJ5g66w2-142d4bXTCsmrF34-J7rWw4IUObutQznaml59XdfweiEGKzv1Otp3quffUEA"],
    "data" : {
        "message":"Push di prova",
        "msgcnt":"13"
     }
}
```

I cannot see anything wrong... What am I missing?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Did you found the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Developing a solution with php, I recieved always the same error WHEN the message had Umlauts (e.g. äöü) in it.
Without the message went through and arrived the reciever.

The solution was finally to `utf8_encode( 'your text here äöä' )` your outgoing strings (message, title, etc. whatever).

Cost my at least several hours to detect what was 'wrong'.

Answer (score -1):

Is it the case that you are missing ',' as shown below in bold

```
{
    "registration_ids" : ["APA91bEmD8T9NxQj07uhbTAsD1GTWvT7L_no1SXP70YWaQGPX6VO73pdAOa53PN-hyAyy-3erItWxLDb8W1aQ2nh3np0NttJ5g66w2-142d4bXTCsmrF34-J7rWw4IUObutQznaml59XdfweiEGKzv1Otp3quffUEA"],
    "data" : {
        "message":"Push di prova",
        "msgcnt":"13"**,**
     }**,**
}
```

Refer message given in this link: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#payload

Comment: But technically... Your JSON is invalid, isn't it? I mean: the last field should not have any comma after its value, as far as I know..